# $state.go() is not refreshing in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to reload nested state of different controller when changing selectbox content in AngularJS?

I have 2 select boxes 1.Category and 2.SubCategory

Based on the category and subcategory, Products will be displayed on the inner state

category and subcategory come under addproducts state

products come under .productsettings state inside the addproducts state

But my problem is when I select both category and subcategory the product will be displayed that means

```
$state.go('addproducts.productsettings');
```

will work,But after selecting both after that when i change only subcategory selectbox it won't reload product state

```
$state.go('addproducts.productsettings');
```

will not work that wont load in ProductSettingsController

This is my html code it contains two select boxes

```
  <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Category</b></label>
        <select ng-model="selectedCategory" class="form-control" id="categories" ng-init="selectedCategory = null" 
        ng-change="onCategoryChange(selectedCategory)"> 
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in categories | orderBy:'catName'| groupBy:'catName'">{{key}}</option>           
                </select>           
      </div>              
    </form>     
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

  </div>


  <div class="col-md-3"> 

  <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    <form>    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>SubCategory</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="subcategories" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-disabled="!selectedCategory"
         ng-options="categories.subCatName for categories in categories | filter: {catName:selectedCategory}" ng-change="getValue()">
             <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
      </div>          
    </form>     
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

  </div>
```

This is my js code

```
 var appshop = angular.module('appShop', [ 'ui.router', 'angular.filter' ]);

    appshop.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/category');

        $stateProvider.state('addproducts',
        {
            url : '/addproducts',
            views :
            {                               
                'body' :
                {
                    templateUrl : 'category/manageproduct.htm',
                    controller : 'AddProductController'             
                }
            }
        })

        .state('addproducts.productsettings',
        {
            url : '/productsettings',
            views :
            {                               
                'productsbody@addproducts' :
                {
                    templateUrl : 'category/productsettings.htm',
                    controller : 'ProductsSettingsController'               
                }
            }
        })

    });

    //==========================================================

    appshop.controller('AddProductController',AddProductController);

    function AddProductController($scope, $http,$state)
    {
        $scope.onCategoryChange = function(category) 
        {
            if (!category) 
            {
                $scope.selectedSubCategory = undefined;

            }
        }   
        var categoryPromise = $http.get("../rest/mcategory");
        categoryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            $scope.categories=data;         
        });

        categoryPromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
        {
            alert("Error");     
        });     

        $scope.getValue=function()
        {       
            $state.go('addproducts.productsettings');       
        }   

    }

    //==========================================================

    appshop.controller('ProductSettingsController',ProductSettingsController);

    function ProductSettingsController($scope,$http,$state)
    {
        alert("Clicked")//I need to get alert here

    }
```

That two select boxes are come under AddProductController

And products are comed under nested state of this AddProductController it is named as ProductSettingsController

When i select both category and subcategory it works fine

But after selcting both then only to changed subcategory it wont works

Any idea for getting product details when i select subcatname? I need to get alert Clicked in ProductSettingsController when i changed in subcategory selectbox

Comment: see my answer it's helped u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **$stateParams** means parameters in url: look

HTML **SubCategory section**

```
<!-- ----------------------------------- -->
    <form>    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>SubCategory</b></label>
        <select class="form-control" id="subcategories" ng-model="selectedSubCategory" ng-disabled="!selectedCategory"
         ng-options="categories.subCatName for categories in categories | filter: {catName:selectedCategory}" ng-change="getValue(selectedSubCategory)">
             <option value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
      </div>          
    </form>     
    <!-- ----------------------------------- -->
```

JS **add stateParams in substate**

```
.state('addproducts.productsettings',
        {
            url : '/productsettings?:subitem',
            views :
            {                               
                'productsbody@addproducts' :
                {
                    templateUrl : 'category/productsettings.htm',
                    controller : 'ProductsSettingsController'               
                }
            }
        })
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getValue=function(sub_item)
{       
    $state.go('addproducts.productsettings', {subitem:sub_item});       
}
```

Comment: Hearts of  Sandeep Ji very much.Kya hai its working give me you mail id.Ima from India Kerala Thank you very muchits working Only i change    url : '/productsettings/:subitem', just correct it ok  thank you why without its not working..

Comment: rawatsandeep670@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$state.reload();
```

or

```
$state.go('addproducts.productsettings', {}, {reload: true});
```